# MySQL mysql_info alike message within a stored procedure (both affected and matched row counts)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to figure out how to get both affected row count and matched row count within a stored procedure after UPDATE query. I am aware of ROW_COUNT function, but it only returns number of rows that were actually changed by the query. But how to get number of rows matched by the UPDATE query?

```
ROW_COUNT() - returns the number of changed rows
FOUND_ROWS() - works only with SELECT ... LIMIT query
GET DIAGNOSTICS x = ROW_COUNT - returns the same as ROW_COUNT()
GET DIAGNOSTICS x = NUMBER - returns always 0
GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 x = MESSAGE_TEXT - returns NULL on success
```

In PHP there is mysqli_info() method, that returns great result on UPDATE:

```
Rows matched: 40 Changed: 38 Warnings: 0
```

So, how do I get this message (or these two values - rows matched and rows changed) within a stored procedure?

Or am I forced to run SELECT query with the same WHERE clause before UPDATE to get the number of matched rows? Can the value returned by the SELECT query be trustful when run before actual UPDATE? Can the table change while the stored procedure is running? Or should I lock the table?

Consider MySQL 5.7.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

The best solution I found so far is this (pseudocode):

```
DECLARE _rows_matched, _rows_affected INT;

START TRANSACTION;

SELECT COUNT(1) INTO _rows_matched FROM tbl WHERE {condition X} FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE tbl SET {sets...} WHERE {condition X};
SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO _rows_affected;

COMMIT;

SELECT _rows_matched, _rows_affected;
```

Does SELECT COUNT() ... FOR UPDATE give me concurency-proof number of matched rows until the update is made?

Comment: What's the point of retrieving how many rows matched an update's where clause in a stored proc?

Comment: Result of stored procedure should be a status, whether some records exist at all, how many records exists and how many were updated. An additional SELECT (as another query) is not a solution, because the data might change between SELECT and UPDATE. I only found SELECT ... FOR UPDATE statement, that is the best solution so far, as it locks the selected rows for the next UPDATE. But it's not the same.